# Custom layout for log4j

Tags: java, log4j

There is a way to print different layout for different log level? For example:

logger.warn("Message");
print something like this: 2016-06-20 13:34:41,245 INFO (main:) Message
and for logger.info("Message2");
print just: Message2

Is possible to do that? To define one layout to warn e other layout for info

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n %d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n
```

Comment: Are you using log4j.xml to configure this? Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using?

Comment: The version is: 1.2.17

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to log4j version 2.x or it is a requirement to use log4j1.2.17?

Comment: It's possible to upgrade to log4j 2.x

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but it should work. If you define two appenders and you assign a pattern for each appenders. Then the keyword **Threshold** should filter the level
:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileWarning, fileInfo, stdout

log4j.appender.fileWarning=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileWarning.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.fileWarning.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.fileWarning.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileWarning.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileWarning.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n %d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n
log4j.appender.fileWarning.Threshold=WARNING

log4j.appender.fileInfo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileInfo.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.fileInfo.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.fileInfo.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileInfo.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.fileInfo.Threshold=INFO
```

Hope it's help.